# Android, How to show location enable dialog again, if user has denied it once

Tags: android, android-location

I have a situation where I am showing the Location Enable dialog, If user declines it once, I am not able to show the dialog again though I am repeatedly calling the method `startResolutionForResult()`

P.S: I am not showing the option to select `never` in the dialog, so it should show the dialog everytime.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: my code is working fine so far.. it shows the dialog the enable location, but once user denies it and again if i trying to show the location using the same code. The dialog doesn't pop up. Its the same universal code. I don't think the same code is required here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following routine to request for a Location Settings Dialog and it's working as expected, meaning if the user denies it (by tapping `Not Now`) it pops up again if requested.

```
protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);


    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
    builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();

    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    mLocationSettingsRequest);
    result.setResultCallback(this);
}
@Override
public void onResult(@NonNull LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
    final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
    switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
            Log.i(TAG, "All location settings are satisfied.");
            startLocationUpdates();
            break;
        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
            Log.i(TAG, "Location settings are not satisfied. Show the user a dialog to" +
                    "upgrade location settings ");
            try {
                status.startResolutionForResult(HostActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "PendingIntent unable to execute request.");
            }
            break;
        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
            Log.i(TAG, "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be fixed here. Dialog " +
                    "not created.");
            break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Log.i(TAG, "User agreed to make required location settings changes.");
                    Util.toast(HostActivity.this, R.string.requesting_location_data);
                    startLocationUpdates();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Log.i(TAG, "User chose not to make required location settings changes.");
                    break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Using this code I believe you could achieve the same.

Bear in mind that your `Activity` or `Fragment` must implement `ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>`.